# Redirection from Subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to redirect `test.subdomain.com` to `subdomain.com/web`

I want to redirect all pages and posts as well.

I did redirection from cpanel it will redirects only home page and then I put some code in .htaccess

This code is not working for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.subdomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.subdomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.subdomain\.com\blog
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/subdomain\.com\/web" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.subdomain.com/web/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.subdomain.com/web/blog/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirection is a wordpress plugin that supports the feature you're inquiring about.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

https://snag.gy/vFp2j3.jpg

Comment: I mostly use "301 Redirect" but I don't think they support subdomains, only directories & files... (domain.com/something.* >> newdomain.com/something*)

Comment: But for that i have to redirect it page by page and i have 500 links to redirect (blog post and other links are included)

Comment: Use wildcards? You said it's ALL pages & posts. oldsubdomain.olddomain.com/* >> newdomain.com/

Comment: I tried wildcards but still it doesnot redirects pages and posts.

Comment: I'm doing it on my end with no issue. Please refer to the snaggy link.